# How to add a dynamic weather ticker to the webpage

Tags: language-agnostic

All Weather Tickers I found are static and if the user wants to select a zip code it links you to a different page.

Do you know any weather ticker that just gets the new info  in the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RICO](http://demos.openrico.org/weather_demo) has an AJAX weather widget that seems to be along the lines of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this yourself - you can generally get this data from [the National Weather Service's METARs](http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/metar.shtml).  [Here's the METAR for the Rochester, NY airport](http://weather.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/mgetmetar.pl?cccc=KROC). They're available in all sorts of ways (XML, FTP), and there are lots of parsers out there.